# Is there an organization that offers a Hashicorp Vault SaaS solution?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, software-as-a-service

There is [a number of recommendations](https://www.vaultproject.io/guides/production.html) to harden a Hashicorp Vault deployment, but is there a SaaS solution, like CloudBees offers Jenkins to prevent that the hardening should be done manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Hashicorp itself offers an enterprise solution including 24x7 gold support called [Hashicorp Vault premium enterprise](https://www.hashicorp.com/products/vault).

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there are no services today that offer Vault SaaS. However, if you're looking for a better UI/UX, there are great options out there for a Vault UI (A full Hashicorp supported list can be found [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/relatedtools.html)). I've personally tried out both [Cryptr](https://github.com/adobe/cryptr) and [Goldfish](https://vault-ui.io/#/) and have found both to be robust and complete.

Comment: Will you use Cryptr or goldfish in production? Could you explain why?

Comment: Im an intern right now to be honest, but from experience with both I think I would go with goldfish. Their UI is beautiful, the insulation on my Ubuntu system was easy, and the community supporting this is more active.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late (like by 2 years lol), but [akeyless.io](https://www.akeyless.io) is a SaaS secrets management tool. You can see more info compared to [other tools here](https://datafloq.com/read/5-compelling-alternatives-hashicorp-vault/11244).

Comment: please improve your answer: add a relevant hyperlink to it, and some minimal description about what it is about, and/or what is so special/unique about it.